# Is there a way to have an on edit function be triggered by only one user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For work I have a tracker on a google sheet that I share with 5 other people (we each have a sheet within a shared worksheet). I use an on edit code to help me with my tasks, but it seems to have slowed down significantly recently and I'm not sure why. Is there any way to make it so the code is only triggered if I'm the one editing the google sheet? Below is the code I have currently and the executions log. [enter image description here][1]

````
  const cs = e.source;
  const cel = e.range;  
  const rw = cel.getRow();
  const col = cel.getColumn();
  const s1 = cs.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const s2 = cs.getSheetByName("TimeZones");
  const ZONES = s2.getDataRange().getValues();

  if(s1 == '3193:RENA' &&  rw < 15){
    var val = cel.getValue();
    Logger.log(val);
      if(col == 5){
        for (var i=0;i<52;i++){
          if(ZONES[i][0] == val){
            tz = ZONES[i][2];
            cel.offset(0,1).setValue(tz);
            cel.setFontWeight(400)}}}
        else if(col == 7){
          cel.setValue("-"+val)
          cel.setFontWeight(400)}
  }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDkqX.png
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your question, because of incomplete script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, about `Is there any way to make it so the code is only triggered if I'm the one editing the google sheet?`, are you the owner of the Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const users = ["email1","email2"]
  const sh1 = e.range.getSheet();
  const ZONES = e.source.getSheetByName("TimeZones").getDataRange().getValues();
  if (~users.indexOf(e.user.email) && sh1.getName() == '3193:RENA' && e.range.rowStart < 15) {
    if (e.range.columnStart == 5) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        if (ZONES[i][0] == e.value) {
          tz = ZONES[i][2];
          e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(tz);
          e.range.setFontWeight(400)
        }
      }
    }
    else if (e.range.columnStart == 7) {
      e.range.setValue("-" + e.value)
      e.range.setFontWeight(400)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I removed the regular trigger and used this code and now it just keeps timing out.

Comment: I couldn't edit my previous comment  but when I use this code as provided as a simple trigger it times out however when I use it as an installable trigger it works. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Please post a copy of your current code in your question.  Also I hope you realize that the onEdit(e) function cannot be called unless you supply the event object either from a trigger or through an intermediate function

Comment: I do thank you. It was timing out as a simple trigger but once I only had one portion of the code active at a time (to check execution times) it started working at normal speeds. Not sure what the issue was but it seems to be resolved for now.

Comment: An installable trigger can perform operations that require permission.  A simple trigger cannot.